# Localization with variable and constant definition in header file

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, localization

How do I use NSLocalizedString in this case when I have a header where I define a few parameters, say:

```
#define appKey @"appKey1 is: %@"
```

I think I know that my Localizable.strings should look like that:

```
"blabla" = "appKey1 is: %@"
```

but how do I use NSLocalizedString? I read that I need to use stringWithFormat, but not sure how...

thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would define your constant as:

```
#define appKey NSLocalizedString(@"appKey1 is: %@", @"appkey constant")
```

Then it should get picked up by the genstrings tool in the usual way.

In the strings file it would then come out like this:

```
/* appkey constant */
"appKey1 is: %@" = "appKey1 is: %@";
```

And you would translate just the right hand side.

Comment: so essentially what you are saying is that in the header file I should not do anything different, cause it will pick up the %@ from the strings file?

Comment: I'm not really sure what you are asking. Are you trying to localize the app key itself, or the message that says "appKey1 is ..."? To actually print the app key you'll need to use Joel's answer, my answer is just about localizing the message.

Answer (score 2):

String literals are acceptable in NSLocalizedStrings.  What you need to do is something like

```
#define appKey NSLocalizedString(BlahBlah , comments);

"BlahBlah" = "appKey1 is: %@";
```

(Be sure to end your lines with a semi-colon in Localizable.strings, or it will end up being corrupted).

Answer (score 1):

This is how you would do it normally,

```
NSString * myString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"appKey1 is: %@",yourAppKeyString];
```

Since you have it defined you can use it like so

```
NSString * myString = [NSString stringWithFormat:appKey,yourAppKeyString];
```

Either case both would fill your myString like so

```
yourAppKeyString = @"keyString";
myString = @"appKey1 is: keyString";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString * myString = [NSString stringWithFormat: NSLocalizedString(@"appKey", @""),yourAppKeyString];
```